# Arabic render incorrectly in CSS

Tags: html, css, arabic

I have the following HTML & CSS code as follow

```
<span class="outer">
  <span class="inner">ب</span>َ
</span>
```

```
.inner {
  color: rgb(0, 152, 188);
}
```

The inner layer should be colored, while the outer layer should not be colored.

But since the inner contain `ب` and outer contain  `َ`

And that 2 character in arabic is merge to form a single letters, the outer also get colored. How can I avoid this? And only get the `ب` colored and let  `َ` without colored.

I expected the result to be like this
[image: EXPECTED] .
But getting this instead
[image: GET]

Comment: FYI Arabic can’t be represented in ascii

Comment: I also think those characters are getting combined and there’s no way to color separate parts

Comment: Understood.. But is there any single method to solve this problem? I separate the character and put this `   َ  ` into another span and assign different class also would not make any different. I put whitespace between it, it solve the colorize problem but it produce different output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of pure css you may separate those 2 symbols (held in the `content` css property so to make it more friendly relative to the html) and use pseudo elements that will be absolute positioned relative to the `.arabic` container.

For completeness I might say that the vowel mark doesn't fit perfectly the size of the underlying letter... a solution could be changing the `font-size` of it independently but result may vary.

```css
.arabic{
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2rem;  
}

.arabic::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'ب'; /* arabic letter */
  color: rgb(0, 152, 188); 
}

.arabic::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'َ'; /* vowel mark */
}
```

```html
<span class="arabic"></span>
```

While if you wanted to keep your html unchanged like what you showed in your question, the key for the `.inner` style to work correctly was adding `position: absolute;`.

I think the reason why it didn't work otherwise, it's because internally the phrasal content gets merged in one single inline (block) earning the `.inner` style as a whole. While if you define the position differently, it forces the inner content as not being inline keeping them divided.

***But I'm not sure about that.***

(I'm vaguely referring to [ligatures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Ligature)) but I'm going far beyond the scope of my knowledge here.

```css
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(0, 152, 188);
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  <span class="inner">ب</span>َ
</span>
```